# How do I swap elem using jQuery.ui.sortable and jquery.ui.swappable

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, swap

I'm a beginner in JQuery. My problem is I want to insert the dragged item, but sometimes I want to swap two elements.
I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 2):

For swapping you could do something like this:

You have to convert the existing order into array, define one first:

```
var prevPagesOrder = [];
```

Then you check the array after you dropped the element (captured by sortable's stop)

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
       prevPagesOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var currentOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var move_id = ui.item[0].id;
        var swap_index = currentOrder.indexOf(move_id);
        var swapped_id = prevPagesOrder[swap_index]

        // do stuff for swapping
        // move_id = object moved
        // swapped_id = object swapped with
        }
        return true;
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Hope this helps. Would be good if in the future you show people what you have tried so far.